# How can I get the src attribute of a child img element while looping through an array of divs?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to loop through some `<div>` tags and get the `src` attribute of the child `<img>` element but I am not sure how to do it. This is what I have so far.

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".imgs .imagecont");

imgClick = (event) => {
  console.log(event.target.src);
};

imgs.forEach(img => img.addEventListener("click", imgClick));
```

```html
<div class="imgs">
  <div class="imagecont">
    <img src="assets/img1.jpeg">
  </div>
  <div class="imagecont">
    <img src="assets/img2.jpeg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Also, I have to use **vanilla javascript**.

Comment: What's wrong with your current code - seems to work fine?  Or are you just wanting to get the source without the domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with [`Element.getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute)

> The `getAttribute()` method of the Element interface returns the value of a specified attribute on the element.

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".imgs .imagecont");

imgClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute('src'));
};

imgs.forEach(img => img.addEventListener("click", imgClick));
```

```html
<div class="imgs">
    <div class="imagecont">
        <img src="assets/img1.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="imagecont">
        <img src="assets/img2.jpeg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using `getAttribute('src')`

```js
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll(".imgs .imagecont");

imgClick = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute('src'));
};

imgs.forEach(img => img.addEventListener("click", imgClick));
```

```html
<div class="imgs">
    <div class="imagecont">
        <img src="assets/img1.jpeg">
    </div>
    <div class="imagecont">
        <img src="assets/img2.jpeg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer and @Mamun's are freakishly identical!

Comment: and are only 3 seconds apart, I noticed.